# How to post about build start into slack?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, slack, slack-api

Can I use slackSend command in jenkins flow dsl if i have Jenkins ver. 1.656.
I have enabled Slack Notification Plugin and it works fine in most cases, but i wish to display message when build starts.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up script in the pipeline, should be something like this:

```
def notify(status) {
    slackSend channel: "#jenkins", 
    color: '#d71f85',
    message: "${status}", 
    tokenCredentialId: 'yourtoken'
}

pipeline{
 ....
 stages{
    stage('Buildstart) {
      steps {
        notify("Build Started")
      }
    }
   ....
 }
}
```